# Webhosting: SSD vs. HDD animation speed

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am currently searching for a provider to host a website that I created. Since the site contains a few performance-expensive animations (mostly because of a fullscreen-slider that includes filter + scaling transitions), I am in need of a provider that would ensure a comparably good performance. I already tested the page in different real-world scenarios via a free server solution. Mostly everything went fine except for a bit of stuttering within Microsoft Edge and on some older machines.

Since there are providers who offer webhosting via SSD's against others that still only provide HDD's to store the data, I was asking myself in how far this could also have an impact on the performance of the website's animations. Or does the type of harddrive not count when it comes to animation-speeds?

I would really appreciate every piece of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations run in the browser on the client machine after it finished downloading your page code and resources. Hence, animations aren't affected by your hosting storage technology.